# mouseenter mouseleave events conflict ? jquery

Tags: jquery, html, events, mouseover, mouseleave

I am trying to animate my navigation menu with the help of jquery.

for this purpose, i have written the following code.

html

```
<nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><p class='active'>one</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><p class='inactive'>two </p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><p  class='inactive'>three</p></a></li>
    </ul>   
</nav>
```

jquery

```
    $safed_text = "";       

    $('.inactive').on('mouseenter',function(){
        $safed_text = $(this).text();
        $(this).css("font-size", "0.7em");
        $(this).text("comming soon...");
        $(this).css("display", "none");
        $(this).fadeIn("slow");
    });

    $('.inactive').on('mouseleave',function(){
        $(this).css("font-size", "1em");
        $(this).text($safed_text);

    });
```

the code works for the most part as expected i.e. changing the text of the two last elements when hovered over with the mouse.

However, if one hovers over the two of them to quickly, the text doesnt change as expected and no text is displayed.

Why is this happening ? What kind of workarounds are there ?

Thank you.

https://jsfiddle.net/dtkbf5r8/

Comment: It's working fine. (you didn't include jquery) https://jsfiddle.net/dtkbf5r8/1/

Comment: This is hepnning because you applied both $(this).css("display", "none");
        $(this).fadeIn("slow"); please use one of them

Comment: sorry i forgot to include the jquery in jsfiddle, but no that is not the problem. Once you hover back and forth over one of the last two elements you will notice what i am refering to.

Comment: What us the use of these two lines, your requirement is simple on hover text should change and on leave it should again change?

Comment: Thanks Yogesh Sharma for pointing out the problem. I somehow had in my mind i had to hide the text first before i can fade it in. - this solved the problem.

Comment: happy to hear it's working!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below solution, there is no need of display:none if your requirement is to show coming soon text on hover and same text as earlier on mouse leave. -

```js
  $safed_text = "";       

    $('.inactive').on('mouseenter',function(){
        $safed_text = $(this).text();
        $(this).css("font-size", "0.7em");
        $(this).text("comming soon...");
        //$(this).css("display", "none");
        $(this).fadeIn("slow");
    });

    $('.inactive').on('mouseleave',function(){
        $(this).css("font-size", "1em");
        $(this).text($safed_text);

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><p class='active'>one</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><p class='inactive'>two </p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><p  class='inactive'>three</p></a></li>
    </ul>   
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Used to **[.hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)** jQuery

Bind one or two handlers to the matched **elements**, to be executed when the **mouse** pointer **enters** and **leaves** the **elements**

as like this

```js
$( ".inactive" ).hover(
  function() {
            safed_text = $(this).text();
            $(this).css("font-size", "0.7em");
            $(this).text("comming soon...");
            $(this).fadeIn("slow");
  }, function() {
            $(this).css("font-size", "1em");
            $(this).text(safed_text);
  }
);
```

```css
nav{
 width:100%; 
}

nav ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:center;
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
    background: #F1F0D1
}

nav ul li{
 display:inline-block;
/* border: 1px solid #878E63; */
 width: 15%;
}
nav ul li a{
 text-decoration: none;
}


nav ul li a p{
 background: #F1F0D1;
 display: block;
 padding: 5% 12%;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 1em;
 color: #878E63;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
}

nav ul li a p:hover{
 background-color: #878E63;
 color: #F1F0D1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#"><p class='active'>nueng</p></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><p class='inactive'>dos </p></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><p  class='inactive'>drei</p></a></li>
  </ul> 
 </nav>
```

Comment: this is very nice as well. I had read before that hover was deprecated but now that i checked the API that turned out to be false. i have to say its a bit hard to read, if one doesnt know that the first function is for mouseenter and the second one for mouseleave.